# Calculate Euclidean distance using Painless in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, euclidean-distance

I would like to sort results from Elasticsearch according to Euclidean distance between document double array and double array from "params". For now I am using my own solution that calculate this distance.

[image]

Could I use some library method to improve performance? 
For example: Apache Commons Math library in Java provides such method as `EuclideanDistance::compute(double[] a, double[] b)`

Comment: How many dimensions does your vector have? If you have 2 or fewer, you can use elasticsearch's geo point datatype.

Comment: @IanGabes I have more than 200 dimensions, so I need common solution for N dimensions, thanks for suggestion